# chosen not updating in casecading onchange event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, database

```
 $('#FL').chosen();
function Action(code) {
    //alert(code);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ThirdLevel/ShowData?message=" + code,
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
            var s = '<option value="-1">Select First Level</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].AccountNo + '">' + data[i].AccountTitle + '</option>';
            }
           
            $('#FL').html(s);
        }
    });
    $("#FL").trigger("chosen:updated")
};
```

This Is My Html Code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label><b>Select Account Head</b></label>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ThirdLevel.Headid, new SelectList(Model.HeadList, "id", "HeadName"), "Select Account Head", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "chosen-select form-control", onChange = "Action(this.value)", style = "height:35px" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <label><b>Select First Level</b></label>
                                            @if (Model.ThirdLevel.id == 0)
                                            {
                                                <select class="form-control" style="height:33px" id="FL" name="SubHead" onChange="Action1(this.value)">
                                                    <option value="">Select First Level</option>
                                                </select>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <select class="form-control" name="SubHead" style="height:33px" id="FL" readonly>
                                                    <option value="">Select First Level</option>
                                                    @foreach (var lst in Model.FirstList)
                                                    {
                                                        <option value="@lst.AccountNo" @if (lst.AccountNo == Model.ThirdLevel.SubHeadid) { <text> selected </text> ; } else { }>@lst.AccountTitle</option>
                                                    }
                                                </select>
                                            }

                                        </div>
```

I want to update the Second drop downlist on change event when the chosen library is not linked it works perfectly but when I use chosen library its doesn't work I am also using the trigger.
`$("#FL").trigger("chosen:updated")`

> Please Help me out I had searched A lot But could not find the solution I'm new to javascript.

**Thanks In advance**

Comment: If you are using a really old version of chosen you might have to use .trigger('liszt:updated')

Comment: No i am using Version 1.8.7

Comment: OK So when you do the $('#FL').html(s); You actually just writing the options html to that stage.. I assume that is is there for writing over the actual select html code... Can you post what $("#FL") actually is..

Comment: @mkane Please Check Out my Updated Code